# For loop and If statement confusion

Tags: android, if-statement, for-loop

Ok so this is not my first for loop in Java, I have been coding for over a year now but for some reasons I cannot seem to get the idea here,  have a drawer which contains categories, each category can/cannot have a description, if a User tries to add a category that exists, the program first checks if the description is the same, if it is, it prompts the user to change either description or Category, below is my code, first time I run it, it works properly second time, it prompts users the user but also adds the category instead of returning, any help will be highly appreciated. `

```
 private void addCategory(String category, String description)
   {
    if(drawer.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        addDrawerItem(category, description);


    }else {
        for (int i = 0; i < drawer.getItems().size(); i++) {

            if (category.toUpperCase().equals(drawer.getItem(i).getTextPrimary())
                    && description.equals(drawer.getItem(i).getTextSecondary())) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Category with same description exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else {

                    addDrawerItem(category, description);
                    return;


            }

        }

    }
}`
```

Comment: I think 'toUpperCase()' can make you problem when you try to compare

Comment: the String in getTextPrimary is in Caps so I have to convert it to caps before I can compare it otherwise its returning false to all my searches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work better:

```
private void addCategory(String category, String description) { 
    if (drawer.getItems().isEmpty()) { 
        addDrawerItem(category, description);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < drawer.getItems().size()); i++) {
            if (category.toUpperCase().equals(drawer.getItem(i).getTextPrimary().toUpperCase())
                    && description.equals(drawer.getItem(i).getTextSecondary())) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Category with same description exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }

        addDrawerItem(category, description);
    } 
}
```

The loop is only used to find a matching entry. And a new entry is only added if a match is not found. I also added a `toUpperCase()` call to make sure that the category test will work as you apparently intended.

Comment: and it just worked, thanks alot, it was starting to get on my nerves.